# Showing an equation is solved by unit eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vectors

> Show that, for a symmetric matrix $A$, the equation $$(x^T x) A x + \left( \left( x^T x \right)^2 - x^T A x - 1 \right) x = 0$$ is solved by unit eigenvectors of $A$.

---

A simple rearrangement shows that
$$Ax=\frac{(x^TAx+1-(x^Tx)^2)}{x^Tx}x$$

And this is obviously solved by eigenvectors of $A$, since the right hand side is a scalar multiple of $x$. However, the solution I've been given just states this line of working and then says "which is evidently solved by the unit eigenvectors of A". I don't really see how the solutions to this equation needing to be unit vectors is "evident". Could anyone help clear things up?

Comment: Apply $x^T$  from the left hand side to your identity. You will obtain $$x^TAx=x^TAx+1-(x^Tx)^2$$ Therefore $x^Tx=1.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So back to the original equation
$$
(x^Tx)Ax+((x^Tx)^2-x^TAx-1)x=0
$$
let's assume $x$ is an eigenvector of $A$, with $Ax=\lambda x$

Then

$$
\lambda (x^Tx)x+((x^Tx)^2-\lambda x^Tx-1)x=0 \\
((x^Tx)^2+\lambda (x^Tx)-\lambda x^Tx-1)x=0 \\
((x^Tx)^2-1)x=0 
$$
Then given $x$ is either $0$ vector or $x^Tx=1$ it's a uni-norm eigen-vector.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $x$ is a non-zero solution. As you noted, it follows that $Ax = \lambda x$ for some $\lambda$. The left hand side of the second equation can be rewritten as $\lambda x$ and the right hand side can be rewritten as
$$
\frac{(x^TAx+1-(x^Tx)^2)}{x^Tx}x = \frac{(\lambda \|x\|^2+1-\|x\|^2 )}{\|x\|^2}x = 
\left[\frac 1{\|x\|^2} + \lambda - 1 \right]x.
$$
Thus, the equation only holds if
$$
\lambda = \frac{1}{\|x\|^2} + \lambda - 1.
$$